# Confusion in scanf function while entering values for structure using pointer

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
struct invent
{
   char name[20];
   int number;
   float price;
};

int main()
{
   char ch;
   struct invent product[3],*ptr;
   printf("INPUT\n\n");
   for(ptr=product;ptr<product+3;ptr++)
      scanf("%s %d %f",ptr->name,&ptr->number,&ptr->price);

   printf("\nOUTPUT\n\n");
   ptr=product;
   while(ptr<product+3)
   {
      printf("%20s %5d %10.2f\n",ptr->name,ptr->number,ptr->price);
      ptr++;
   }

   return 0;
}
```

Why in `scanf` function for entering name only `ptr->name` is used while entering number and price `&ptr->number`, `&ptr->price` is used. I want to ask why we are using `&` at all because `ptr` is itself storing the address of structure. Here is another code to explain

```
int main()
{
    int a,*p;
    p=&a;
    scanf("%d",p);
    printf("%d",a);
    return 0;
}
```

In the above code we are not using `&p` in `scanf` function because `p` is itself storing the address of `a`, so why use `&ptr->number` and `&ptr->price` for structures.

Answer (score 2):

> Why in scanf function for entering name only ptr->name is used while
>   entering number and price &ptr->number,&ptr->price

Because `ptr->name` is an array and an array's name, in an expression, gets converted into a pointer to its first element. Hence, there's no `&` (address-of) used when passing it to scanf() and using `&ptr->name` would be wrong.
But other scalar types don't have such "decaying" property. Hence, `&` is used.

See: [What is array decaying?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1461432/what-is-array-decaying)
In your second program, `p` is already a pointer. So, passing `&p` would be `int**` whereas `scanf()` expects an `int*` for the format specifier `%d`.

Basically, in both cases you are required to pass pointers (`char*` for `%s` and `int*` for `%d`). But in the case of arrays, the pointer is automagically derived as per the rules of the C standard.

Also relevant: http://c-faq.com/aryptr/aryvsadr.html

Comment: which has higher precedence & or ->

Comment: `->` (dereferencing) binds tighter than `&`(address-of). `&ptr->name` is equivalent to `&(ptr->name)`.

Comment: why (*ptr).number is same as ptr->number

Comment: C standard defines they are equivalent. The reason is probably historical and also for ease of use. Consider a struct contain pointer to another struct can be written as `p->q->value`. Writing the same using `*` is more cumbersome.